# Generate large amount of sentences based on frequency of the input

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My goal is to generate sentences based on the frequency of the input. For example I have input like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"s":["a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"], "m":[["x", "y"], ["x", "z"], ["y", "w", "z"], ["y"], ["z"], ["z"]]})
>>> df.set_index("s")
>>> df
           m
s
a     [x, y]
a     [x, z]
b  [y, w, z]
b        [y]
c        [z]
c        [z]
```

I want to have a function `gen_sentence(s)` that takes an `s` and generates random non-empty sentence based on the frequency of the letters in column `m`. So `gen_sentence("a")` should generate sentences where all of them would contain `x`, 50% of them should contain `y` and 50% `z`.

My intuition is to transform the DataFrame into a DataFrame of frequency, so for the example something like this:

```
     w  x    y    z
s
a  0.0  1  0.5  0.5
b  0.5  0  1.0  0.5
c  0.0  0  0.0  1.0
```

And then roll a random number for each column given an `s`:

```
def gen_sentence(fdf, s):
    return fdf.columns[np.random.random(len(fdf.columns)) < fdf.loc[s]]
```

**However, I have no clue how to transform the DataFrame in the frequency DataFrame.**

The solution will probably be to use `df.agg["s"]` but what function do I apply on the aggregate?

In reality the dataset is pretty big with over 1 million rows, about 500 different words in `m` en about 100 different values for `s` and the frequency table will be sparse: most `s`'s have a frequency of zero for most words in `m`. Furthermore, I need to generate at least a couple of hundred thousand sentences so I'm trying to find an implementation can generate a sentence as fast as possible. Also, the solution doesn't have to use Panda's, I was just thinking that the vectorized implementation of most of its functions is the fastest solution.

---

**So in short**, first, how do I transform the DataFrame into the frequency DataFrame and second, is there a faster method of generating sentences?

---

I've tested my implementation to see if it's fast enough and it's decent: a frequency DataFrame with 500 rows and 100 columns can generate 5000 sentences in about 1.2 seconds on my machine.

If you want to test your own method against mine, here's my test:

```
import timeit

setup = '''
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def val():
    v = np.random.normal(0, 0.2)
    return v if 0 <= v <= 1 else 0


def gen_sentence(fdf, s):
    return fdf.columns[np.random.random(len(fdf.columns)) < fdf.loc[s]]

n = 500
m = 100
fdf = pd.DataFrame([[val() for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(m)])
fdf = fdf.join(pd.DataFrame({"s": [i for i in range(m)]}))
fdf = fdf.set_index("s")
fdf.columns = ["w%d" % i for i in range(n)]
'''

test = "x = np.random.randint(0, m); gen_sentence(fdf, x)"

print(timeit.timeit(test, setup=setup, number=5000))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Alla Tarighati I now have this solution for the first part of my question:

```
letters = set(x for l in df["m"] for x in l)
for letter in letters:
    df.loc[:, letter] = df.m.apply(lambda x: letter in x)

df = df.drop(["m"], axis=1)

gdf = df.groupby("s")
fdf = gdf.agg(lambda x: sum(x))
fdf = fdf.divide(gdf.size(), axis="index")
print(fdf)
```

output:

```
     y    x    z    w
s                    
a  0.5  1.0  0.5  0.0
b  1.0  0.0  0.5  0.5
c  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
```

Note that in line three I changed the lambda function to `letter in x` so that duplicate letters in a sentence aren't counted multiple times.

And like Alla Tarighati, this isn't a very fast solution, so improvements are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

To transform to frequency dataframe try this (not the best solution, but it works):

```
for letter in ['x', 'y', 'w', 'z']:
    df.loc[:, letter] = df.m.apply(lambda x: x.count(letter))

df = df.drop(['m'], axis=1)

df_1 = df.groupby('s').agg(lambda x: sum(x)).reset_index()

print(df_1)
```

Output:

```
   s  x  y  w  z
0  a  2  1  0  1
1  b  0  2  1  1
2  c  0  0  0  2
```

---

Another alternative (without `for` loop, using `stack` and `pivot_table`):

```
import numpy as np
df_1 = (df.m.apply(pd.Series).stack().to_frame('m')).reset_index().set_index('level_0')['m']
df_1 = pd.concat([df['s'], df_1], axis=1).reset_index()[['s', 'm']]
df_1.insert(1, 'freq', 1)
df_1 = pd.pivot_table(df_1, values='freq', index='s', columns='m', aggfunc=np.sum).fillna(0)
df_1 = df_1.div(df_1.max(axis=1), axis=0)
df_1.columns.name=None

print(df_1)
```

Output:

```
     w    x    y    z
s                    
a  0.0  1.0  0.5  0.5
b  0.5  0.0  1.0  0.5
c  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

Comment: Not exactly, your answer has to be divided by the size of the aggregate, but it helped me do the rest, so thanks!

Comment: I had to add a `df.m = df.m.apply(set).apply(list)` at the start to match my behavior. But even without that, it is slower than my solution. Thanks for your help though.